# How to create a permanent “alias” for ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, alias

If you create an alias for example:

```
alias cls="clear"
```

It exists untill you kill terminall session. When you start a new terminal window the alias doesn't exist any more. How to create "permanent" alias, one that exists in every terminal session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put such aliases in the ~/.bash_aliases file.

That file is loaded by ~/.bashrc. On Ubuntu 10.04, the following lines need to be uncommented to enable the use of ~/.bash_aliases. On Ubuntu 11.04 and later, it's already enabled:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

also

You can add the function below to your .bashrc file.

function permalias ()

```
{ 
  alias "$*";
  echo alias "$*" >> ~/.bash_aliases
}
```

Then open a new terminal or run source ~/.bashrc in your current terminal. You can now create permanent aliases by using the permalias command, for example permalias cls=clear.

Comment: Perfect! exactly what I was looking for. I renamed it "mkalias".

Comment: If you have ruby installed on ubuntu, you can use aka (https://github.com/ytbryan/aka)  to generate permanent aliases with a single command. eg. "aka g hello="echo helloworld"
aka also auto-source the dotfile for you. There's also no need to open dot file with text editor.